# Can I earn trophies in a Private Match?

Tags: ps4, star-wars-battlefront-2015

EA recently added private matches to Battlefront so that you can play with/against your friends.

Can these games affect your progress towards trophies (or achievements on xbox)?

IE I get 3 friends, we each take turns getting the most kills in Blast for "[Playing the Objective](http://www.truetrophies.com/t122367/playing-the-objective-trophy.htm)"

Comment: Someone tried to figure that out, unfortunately it isn't possible in his words. Link is: http://psnprofiles.com/forums/topic/34535-cannot-boost-trophies-in-private-matches/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little looking around it seem that unfortunately you cannot. Which makes sense seeing as it would be a pretty cheap/easy way to get those trophies rather than earning them.

From [this link](http://psnprofiles.com/forums/topic/34535-cannot-boost-trophies-in-private-matches/) @FerdieQO posted in their comment:

> You are unable to boost the trophies in private matches. We tried to get the "What's The Cargo?", "Playing the Objective" and "Precision Shot" in private match but did not unlock :/